# Missing configuration resources in StrutsTestCase 2.1.4

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, struts, web.xml, struts-config

I'm trying to use StrutsTestCase 2.1.4 to do unit testing on my Struts application. But when I tried to run the test, a "missing configuration resources for path /WEB-INF/web.xml" error happens.

I looked it up in the FAQ of StrutsTestCase, and followed the instruction to add my application path to the classpath. However, it didn't work.

Then I use the setConfigFile() method to specify the path of web.xml and struts-config.xml. As you see, it didn't work, either.

Here's the setUp() method override in my test class:

```
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        File web = new File("E:/JavaPros/stolon/STOLONCAS/web/");
        this.setContextDirectory(web);
        this.setConfigFile("E:/JavaPros/stolon/STOLONCAS/web/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        this.setConfigFile("E:/JavaPros/stolon/STOLONCAS/web/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml");
    }
```

One thing different by using this method is the error msg became "Missing configuration resource for path E:/JavaPros/stolon/STOLONCAS/build/web/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml". This makes me very confused for I'm absolutely sure that there is the struts-config.xml in that path.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260218/strutstestcase-the-web-inf-web-xml-was-not-found will help?

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that before.